# Importing an external game map for a level (saved as `.js`) in Javascript and HTML canvas

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I making a 2D platformer game, and have made 3 levels fro the game in a software called Tiled. Tiled gave me the options to save the map as `.tmx`, `.json` or `.js`. Since I am making a web game, I have decided to save all of the maps as `.js`. In addition, I am using the HTML canvas for the output. However, as the levels are considerably larger than the size of the canvas, I am, firstly, unsure of how to import the map into my HTML or JavaScript, and then, secondly, how to display the level in the canvas.

Comment: here is not a forum to ask some questions and get an answer, you have to explain a code problem, and the community helps you. if you have such a basic question use google: https://gamedevacademy.org/html5-phaser-tutorial-top-down-games-with-tiled/

Answer (score 0):

Firstly you should load the map as JSON file for example `map.json`

```
fetch('map.json')
.then(res => res.json())
.then(data => {

// do something with the map data.

})
```

after you load the data i would recommend you to watch some tutorials on 2DArrays and rendering them onto canvas.

here are some resources :

- [Tile based game development in Javascript](https://youtu.be/txUvD5_ROIU)
- [How to Make HTML5 Games](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XgK4YaMqQFg&list=PLh-MBXZEiyMhulEqYE3gn63idSAKG6Sx1)